# Overriding default control templates - ListTitleViewSelectorMenu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, controltemplate

I am following the example given here to override the default DocumentLibraryForm rendering template

[MSDN - Override a Default Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544582%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="DocumentLibraryForm" runat="server">
... Custom stuff here ..
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

*(Thats the 2007 version, the [2010 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544582%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is the same but not complete, it doesn't show the directives)*

And that all works just fine. There are lots of other examples on t'internet of overriding control rendering templates.

However I am trying to override things like ListTitleViewSelectorMenu and that isn't working.

```
<!-- Definition from allitems.aspx -->
<SharePoint:ListTitleViewSelectorMenu AlignToParent="true" id="LTViewSelectorMenu" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharePoint:RenderingTemplate` can only be used to override defined templates, usually in the generation of forms and list views. I dont think they can be used to replace random controls that are placed on page layouts.

I think i have tried what you are trying do, customise that view dropdown on list layout pages. I have an control that shows it sorted. The way that you replace controls is with a `DelegateControl` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470880.aspx), but unfortuately `ListTitleViewSelectorMenu` is not wrapped by a `DelegateControl` in the standard list layouts. You may have to replace the entire bread crumb.

Comment: Cheers - so to replace it you're looking at editing listitems.aspx or <shudder> something in the main list schema?

Comment: yeah i just replace the control in the view aspx. If you were really keen you could write a httpmodule or control that found the existing control, hide it and insert your new one (for a global replace)